# Why does a regular for loop not seem to work in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I have some code here, can anyone tell me why the for loop doesn't work the way I expect it to?

```
$(function(){
    var details = $("<li> New list item</li>")
    for( i=0; i<3;i++){
        $('#list').append(details);
        console.log(i);     
    };
});
```

I'm expecting this to add 3 new list items.  But it adds one and then nothing...  The console.log does output 3 times though, so why doesn't the append happen 3 times?

The code is not useful, I'm just learning jQuery and wanted to understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: You need to clone it. You are readding the same DOM node.

Comment: `details` - `$("<li> New list item</li>")` - is a jQuery object containing a DOM element reference. Every time you append it, you're appending the same element to the `$('#list')`. An element can only have a single place in the DOM tree, hence you're doing nothing but "detaching" the element and appending it back to the same place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a [DOM element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_element.asp) is appended to another it is actually removed from its original location and inserted in the new location. For instance, suppose you have this HTML code:

```
<div id="p1">
    <div id="c1">Child</div>
</div>
<div id="p2">
</div>
```

And you execute the following JavaScript code:

```
$('#p2').append($('#c1'));
```

Then, the resulting HTML will be:

```
<div id="p1">
</div>
<div id="p2">
    <div id="c1">Child</div>
</div>
```

That's why your loop isn't adding any new items to your list after the first iteration, because it is *relocating* a DOM element to the same location it already is! To insert new items to your list you need to do as **Sam** suggests, and clone the original item before appending it to the list:

```
$('#list').append(details.clone());
```

Comment: thanks for explaining that!  I didn't care about the solution as much as I was trying to understand what was happening :)

Answer (score 0):

Just clone

```
$(function(){
var details = $("<li> New list item</li>");
for( i=0; i<3;i++){
    $('#list').append(details.clone());
    console.log(i);     
 };
});
```